# How can I make Flash video content on Dell (Windows 11) when Adobe Flash player has been “Retired?”

Tags: flash-player, windows-11-v22h2

How can I make Flash video content on Dell (Windows 11) when Adobe Flash player has been “Retired?”

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What's the name of the technology, following on Flash? (I believe that's a better question :-) )

Comment: are you referring to FLV files? ffmpeg still supports the format

Answer (score 4):

> How can I make Flash video content on Dell (Windows 11) when Adobe Flash player has been “Retired?”

You cannot. Flash Player has been retired a long time - long before Windows 11.

Your only hope now is to develop a new approach without Flash. Everyone else has done that.